# How to find if pandas dataframe has "NA" values in html code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The dataframe variable has "NA" value if data is not written into it.

If a table has 'NA' values like this [table display in web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGzq5.jpg)  then table shouldn't appear on webpage. The table is fetched from python dataframe 'resourse_usage' from the server
And the html code written is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTnLT.jpg)

Help me out here that how can I manipulate the python variable in html code so that the table isn't displayed if it has entire row with "NA" values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have loaded the data into dataframe called `df`, you can use `df = df.dropna()` to keep only the rows without any `NaN` values (so if there is even one column with a `NaN` in a row, the row will still be dropped). If instead, you only want to drop rows where the entry for every column in each row is `NaN`, then you can use `df = df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[1])`.